# Method to find second highest number in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Getting output of 0 each time when im ment to get 3 looked over my code my not sure where i have gone wrong i can do it without using a method i know but just trying to practice java

```
public class App {
    
    public static int second(int a[],int n) {
        int[] arr = new int [n];
        int temp;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++) {
                if(arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return arr[n-2];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1,3,2,5,3};
        int n = 5;
        int result = second(arr,n);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are sorting `arr` but it doesn't have any values in it. Either sort and use `a` or copy the values of `a` into `arr`.

Comment: Also, you algorithm won't work for an array like `{1,2,5,3,5}` because of the duplicate fives.

Comment: Note: any of the methods that involve sorting will be at least O(n log n); yours is O(n^2). But you can find the second highest number in an array in linear time.

Comment: ..and the (most intuitive) method to "find second max" involves only a O(n) algorithm ...and no "sorting" ...`int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, secondMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE; for (i = 0...n-1) ...if(a[i] > max){...} else if(a[i] > secondMax){...} /*..end of loop*/ ...return secondMax; /*end of algorithm*/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the array parameter name arr and remove the declaration or copy the values from a to arr.

```
public static int second(int arr[],int n) {
    int temp;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++) {
            if(arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr[n-2];
}
```

The reason you get zero is because the primitive int cannot be null. So, when you create the array of length 5, it starts out filled with zeroes.

Comment: yah cheers for this rlly helped didnt know realise now it has to be within scope

Answer (score 0):

Doing it by using streams:

```
public static int second(int a[]) {
    return Arrays.stream(a)
            .sorted()
            .skip(a.length - 2)
            .findFirst()
            .getAsInt();
}
```

I removed the second argument. It sorts your array and skips all the elements prior to the one you want, before picking the now first element.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int second(int[] arr) {
    int highest = arr[0];
    int second = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int j = arr[i];
        if (j >= highest) {
            highest = j;
        } else if (j > second) {
            second = j;
        }
    }
    return second;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1, 3, 2, 5, 3};
    int result = second(arr);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Try this `int[] arr = {10,19,5};`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that doesn't require sorting.

```
int[] arr = { 10, 2, 3, 19, 2, 3, 5 };
System.out.println(second(arr));
```

prints

```
10
```

- set `largest` to the first value in the array
- set `secondLargest` to the smallest possible
- now iterate thru the array.
- if the current value is greater than largest:

  - replace secondLargest with Largest
  - replace largest with current value
- else check to see if current value is greater than secondLargest and assign if true.

```
public static int second(int arr[]) {
    int largest = arr[0];
    int secondLargest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > largest) {
            secondLargest = largest;
            largest = arr[i];
        } else if (arr[i] > secondLargest) {
            secondLargest = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return secondLargest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int second(int arr[],int n) {
    int temp;
    if(arr.length < 2) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++) {
            if(arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr[n-2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int a[] = {23,14,56,77,66,67};
    int high = 0;
    int sec = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i <a.length; i++){
        if(high < a[i]){
            sec = high;
            high = a[i];
        }
        else if(sec < a[i]){
            sec = a[i];
        }
        
    }
    System.out.println("the first highest number is " + high);
    System.out.println("the second highest number is " + sec);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int sec(){
    int arr[] = {12,3,67,4,5,65};
    int high = 0;
    int low = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i ++){
        
        if(high < arr[i]){
            low = high;
            high = arr[i];
        }
        else if(low < arr[i]){
            low = arr[i];           
            }
    }
    return low;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    sch obj = new sch();
    int a = obj.sec();
    
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

}

Comment: I'd recommend to  not just paste code, explain how and why it answers the question.

Comment: explain why this answer is better than the other older answers

Answer (score 0):

package com;
public class FindSecondHighestNumberInArray {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int []arrayOfIngeger = {-23,-989,-878,-2,-5,-3,-4,-123,-345,-98,-675,-98};
    int highestNumber = arrayOfIngeger[0];
    int secHighestNumber = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < arrayOfIngeger.length; i++  ) {
        if(highestNumber < arrayOfIngeger[i]) {             
            secHighestNumber = highestNumber; 
            highestNumber = arrayOfIngeger[i];  
        }else if(secHighestNumber < arrayOfIngeger[i] && arrayOfIngeger[i] != highestNumber) {
            secHighestNumber = arrayOfIngeger[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("second Highest Number in Array   :  "+secHighestNumber);
}
```

}

Comment: Hi @Raghubir Singh it is a good practice to describe how and why your algorithm works.

Comment: Time complexity of this algorithm is O(n). iterating throught only one for loop for this program.

Answer (score 0):

List list=Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);

```
 int secHighest=list.stream().sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()).distinct().skip(1).findFirst().get();
 System.out.println(secHighest);
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
package testpackage;

public class SecondHighestInTheArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] arr = {1,3,11,23,19};
        int firstbig=0, secondbig=arr[1];
        int n=arr.length;
        System.out.println("Given array length is : " +n);
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++) {
                if(arr[i]>arr[j]) {
                    firstbig = arr[i];
                    if(arr[j] > secondbig) {
                        secondbig = arr[j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println( "First biggest is " + firstbig);
        System.out.println("Second biggest is " + secondbig);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The original question did not ask how to find the second largest element in an array, it asked what was wrong with the code (in the question) since it was not producing the expected result. So I don't think your answer actually answers the question that was asked. I also suggest that you learn about [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).