# Trying to make a program that can pick out the top two numbers

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TopTwo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a sequence of numbers: ");
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int first = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int firstOccurences = 0;
    int second = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int secondOccurences = 0;
    while(input.hasNextInt()){
        int x = input.nextInt();
        if(x > first){
            first = x;
            firstOccurences = 1;
        }
        else if (x == first){
            firstOccurences += 1;
        }
        if(x>second){
            second = x;
            secondOccurences = 1;
        }
        else if(x<first){
            secondOccurences += 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The highest is " + first + ". Its number of occurences is " + firstOccurences);
    System.out.println("The second highest is " + second + ". Its number of occurrences is " + secondOccurences);
 }
}
```

I'm trying to finish this code but I cannot figure out how to pick out the second highest number and could use some help, it can pick out the top value but not the second so far also it allows user input until anything besides a number is typed eg. fin .
Input: 24,56,62,12,79,-19,-12,-5,5,fin;
Output:The highest is 79. Its number of occurences is 1
The second highest is 2147483647. Its number of occurrences is 5.

Comment: Consider writing the numbers to a [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) as you read them in. Then it's a simple matter of retrieving the highest two numbers in this set.

Comment: I cannot use sorted set as it takes input until the fin so it would store fin aswell and cause the program to crash

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72638619/1552534) out.

Comment: Wouldn't reading `"fin"` cause `hasNextInt()` to return false? Presumably that's what's causing your loop to run to completion without throwing an exception as it's currently written.

Comment: No it keeps going until NextInt is not met so it just ignores it, and takes the other Ints as the input.